# Jquery hover on child effect other child

Tags: jquery

I've been searching for a way to fix this; I've got a div with two things in it: the first is an img and the second is a div. I would like to have it so that, once you hover on the img, the div shows up. but since both the img and the div are children of the first div, I'm having difficulty doing this.

I've tried doing this:

```
        $('.mydiv img').hover(
    function() 
    {
        $(this).parent().children(':nth-child(1)').removeClass('hidden');
    }
```

but It doesn't work

```
<div class='mydiv' style='position: relative; top:216; left:22%;' href='#' id='1'>
    <img src='assets/this/1.png'>

    <div id='Jumper' class='hidden'> <img src='assets/this/G.png' />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>DF-0</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>replace_me</td>
                <td>70</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post HTML too other wise how can we see what you're trying to access?

Comment: You should study jquery's [DOM traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

Comment: Yeah, that HTML is nothing like what you originally described. :-/

Comment: That's better. See my answer.

Comment: Yah i Aplogize, i somehow managed to not C&P the img from the code.@Isherwood you're answer worked, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <img />
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Do this:

```
$('.mydiv img').hover(function() {
    $(this).next('div').show();
});
```